# error con versión de sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

una consulta ayer cambie de version de sql y me di cuenta que no tengo la opcion de  diagrama sql server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguno sabe como solucionar este error por favor

Comment: ¿Eres el owner de la Base de Datos?